# Remove filter based on table with NA

Tags: r, data.table

I'm assigning rows of data to several different groups.  The main issue is there are many groups, but not every group is using the same set of fields.  I would like to set up a reference table that I could loop over  or shove through a function but I don't know how to remove the fields from the filter where they are unneeded.

Below is sample code, I've included a version of my current solution as well as an example table.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

n <- 1000

#Sample Data
ExampleData <- data.table(sample(1:3,n,replace = TRUE),
                          sample(10:12,n,replace = TRUE),
                          sample(letters[1:3],n,replace = TRUE),
                          sample(LETTERS[1:3],n,replace = TRUE))

#Current solution
ExampleData[V1 == 1 & V2 == 11 & V4 == "C", Group := "Group1"]
ExampleData[V1 == 2, Group := "Group2"]
ExampleData[V1 == 3 & V3 == "a" & V4 == "B", Group := "Group3"]


#Example reference table
ExampleRefTable <- data.table(Group = c("Group1","Group2","Group3"),
                              V1 = c(1,2,3),
                              V2 = c(11,NA,NA),
                              V3 = c(NA,NA,"a"),
                              V4 = c("C",NA,"B"))
```

Comment: will there ever be the case of `ExampleData[V1 == 2 & V3 == "a" & V4 == "B", Group := "Group3"]` and hence Group can be Group2 or 3 in this case. That is, groups are non mutually exclusive and are subsets of conditions in another group.

Comment: For the most part they are all mutually exclusive. There are a two or three cases that could be assigned to two groups, with one getting priority. However, since it's only a few, I'm handling those cases separately

Answer (score 4):

(Thanks to @eddi:) You could iterate over rows/groups in the ref table with `by=`:

```
ExampleRefTable[, 
  ExampleData[copy(.SD), on = names(.SD)[!is.na(.SD)], grp := .BY$Group]
, by = Group]
```

For each Group, we are using `.SD` (the rest of the `S`ubset of the ref table `D`ata) for an update join, ignoring columns of `.SD` that are NA. `.BY` contains the per-group values of `by=`.

---

(My original answer:) You could split up the ref table into subsets with non-NA values:

```
ExampleRefTable[, gNA := .GRP, by=ExampleRefTable[, !"Group"]]

RefTabs = lapply(
  split(ExampleRefTable, by="gNA", keep.by = FALSE), 
  FUN = Filter, f = function(x) !anyNA(x)
)
```

which looks like

```
$`1`
    Group V1 V2 V4
1: Group1  1 11  C

$`2`
    Group V1
1: Group2  2

$`3`
    Group V1 V3 V4
1: Group3  3  a  B
```

Then iterate over these tables with update joins:

```
ExampleData[, Group := NA_character_]
for (i in seq_along(RefTabs)){
  RTi = RefTabs[[i]]
  nmi = setdiff(names(RTi), "Group")

  ExampleData[is.na(Group), Group := 
    RTi[copy(.SD), on=names(.SD), x.Group]
  , .SDcols=nmi][]
} 

rm(RTi, nmi)
```

By filtering on `is.na(Group)`, I'm assuming that the rules in the ref table are mutually exclusive.

The `copy` on `.SD` is needed due to [an open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1926).

This might be more efficient than @eddi's way (at the top of this answer) if there are many groups sharing the same missing/nonmissing columns.

---

If you are manually writing your ref table, I would suggest...

```
rbindlist(idcol = "Group", fill = TRUE, list(
  NULL = list(V1 = numeric(), V2 = numeric(), V3 = character(), V4 = character()),
  Group1 = list(V1 = 1, V2 = 11, V4 = "C"),
  Group2 = list(V1 = 2),
  Group3 = list(V1 = 3, V3 = "a", V4 = "B")
))


    Group V1 V2   V3   V4
1: Group1  1 11 <NA>    C
2: Group2  2 NA <NA> <NA>
3: Group3  3 NA    a    B
```

for easier reading and editing.

Comment: or `ExampleRefTable[, ExampleData[copy(.SD), on = names(.SD)[!is.na(.SD)], grp := Group], by = Group]`

Comment: This is amazing thanks Frank and eddi.  I feel pretty good about my DT knowledge, but I still struggle with .SD, it never works for me.  I'm going to go and collapse my ~100 lines into 3.  (Frank thanks for the tip on building the table, for this I'm going to load in a side CSV, but I'll use that trick in the future)

Answer (score 0):

We can loop through the reference data frame and compare it to the example data assigning groups if the conditions are correct, this scales with any size reference table and data, although you may want to vectorize some things if the data is >~100k:

```
lenC<-ncol(ExampleRefTable)
lenT<-nrow(ExampleRefTable)
lenDat<-nrow(ExampleData)

ExampleData$Group<-"NA"

for(i in 1:lenT){
iter=i
Group_Assign<-ExampleRefTable[i,1]
Vals<-ExampleRefTable[iter,2:lenC]
  for(i in 1:lenDat){
    LogicArray<-ExampleData[i,1:4]==Vals
      if(all(LogicArray, na.rm=T)==T){
        ExampleData[i]$Group<-Group_Assign
      }else{
      }
 }
}

> ExampleData
      V1 V2 V3 V4  Group
   1:  1 11  c  C Group1
   2:  2 12  c  B Group2
   3:  2 11  c  A Group2
   4:  3 12  b  B     NA
   5:  1 10  a  C     NA
  ---                   
 996:  3 12  a  B Group3
 997:  2 10  a  C Group2
 998:  1 10  a  A     NA
 999:  1 10  a  B     NA
1000:  1 11  b  C Group1
```

**This example assumes that NA in the reference data can be matched to any value in the example data as long as the position is correct** e.g:

```
#This is assigned Group1 since NA in the ref.table matched c in pos.3
> ExampleRefTable 
   V1 V2 V3 V4  Group 
1:  1 11 NA  C Group1
> ExampleData
   V1 V2 V3 V4  Group
1:  1 11  c  C Group1
```

If NA is supposed to be matched to only NA values (which none were in the example data), you will change this code:

```
 for(i in 1:lenDat){
    LogicArray<-ExampleData[i,1:4]==Vals
    A<-Vals
    B<-ExampleData[i,1:4]
    NAA<-is.na(A)
    NAB<-is.na(B)
    if(all(NAA==NAB)==T && all(LogicArray, na.rm=T)==T){
        ExampleData[i]$Group<-Group_Assign
    }else{
    }
    }
```